# Clarify or remove the [core] tag for new users

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

I regularly see questions from new and relatively new (<100 rep) users which misuse [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) to denote that they are only talking about the "core" of the language, eg. that it is "just java/the core of java". This is not what the tag is about; instead being related to core dumps.

A search for [java][core] reveals pages upon pages of "just java" questions; another search for [c#][core] reveals both "just c#" questions and cpu core questions, which again are not what this tag is for.

I'm sure that one can find similar examples for most languages; the quantity is so much that it almost tempts me to write a script to find all posts tagged [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) which don't include the words "dump" or "linux" so I can robo-retag them.

I think that we should somehow clarify [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) so that it stops being misused in this way, or just remove it entirely and use [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump) instead.

Comment: I think clarification is pointless, since this tag is unclear. Removal seems more logical.

Comment: @ThunderGr This is a question, with multiple possible answers. Particularly given my inexperience with what to do in these sorts of situations, I considered all solutions. In the answers, people can put forward possibilities individually, and as you can see by my accepted answer, I agree that removal is more logical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless there is a product called "core" then the tag is too broad and ambiguous to have any real meaning.

I don't often advocate an outright hell-fire burnination, but this seems to be one tag where that might be appropriate.

> the quantity is so much that it almost tempts me to write a script to find all posts tagged core which don't include the words "dump" or "linux" so I can robo-retag them.

Maybe it would be more efficient to invert that process - retag the linux/dump tagged questions with [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump), then request burnination of [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core). That way there is no need to clarify the definition of `core`, and it won't be misused anymore.

Answer (score 7):

It's too ambiguous. Remove it and retag the questions.

As @slugster points out, a lot of those questions are about linux and should be retagged with for example [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump).

I would like to add that a number of those tags seem to come from people typing a space when tagging a questions with things like [core-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-audio), [core-motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-motion) [core-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-data), [core-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-animation), and [core-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-graphics).

These could probably be automatically retagged ([core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) + [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) → [core-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-audio)) etc.