# Dump the [core]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

[core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) questions currently fall into two categories:

- Questions about core dumps that could have been equally tagged with [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump)
- Questions about "core" services or the unspecific "core"s of products, with no real relationship to one another.

The top 3 [related tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/core/synonyms) for [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) are [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone), and [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), which don't even make any sense. We need to dump [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) from this second category of questions, which is the large majority of all [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) questions, and retag the first category to [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump).

[I've asked about this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250910/clarify-or-remove-the-core-tag-for-new-users), but that time it wasn't an official burninate request.

Comment: iOS is likely a related tag because lots of lower-level Apple frameworks begin with Core (CoreFoundation, Core Audio, Core Bluetooth, Core Animation, etc).

Comment: I fixed around 75 of the [tag:core] + [tag:iOS] questions. Two are left, but I don't know what core means in Xamarin/appcelerator context, so I won't touch them. When I'm done with my real work I'll probably fix the [tag:iPhone] questions as well. Just another 75 or something...

Comment: @Lankymart dumping is pretty standard in this line of work, I think

Comment: @Lankymart 'core dumps' are pretty common, I guess dumping the core, not so much

Comment: @TankorSmash I wanted to write the title as "Dump [core]" but it wasn't long enough :(

Comment: I like your title.  Seems like [core] is a pretty low quality tag... burn it

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304259/dump-minidump-and-memory-dump

Comment: Can we please get some action on this one?

Comment: I think this should be featured.

Comment: When this will be featured? There are 210 questions in the [queue to be featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A20+is%3Aq+%5Bburninate-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename the \[core\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402155/rename-the-core-tag)

Answer (score 15):

**Burnination still appears to be the consensus**, and it was even mentioned in [your other question about the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250910/359284).

Answering the questions from [When to burninate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/159034) for [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Does it describe the contents? *Maybe* the contents of the error ("This says core dump"), but we have [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump) for that. Not that I think [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump) is great or anything, but it's a place to throw all of those questions that can't otherwise be tagged.

Is it unambiguous? Nope. You pointed this out in the main post, and I agree.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

If the question refers to a core dump, yes. If it refers to some core product of a company, possibly.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Tagging questions with core dumps is like tagging questions that throw any type of [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception). Oh wait...

There are usually better tags to use than just [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) or [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump), so I wouldn't say it adds anything meaningful to the post.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope, for the reasons pointed out in the main post.