# Dump [minidump] and [memory-dump]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

### A dump of the current situation

[minidump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minidump) summary (125 items):

> A minidump is a file containing information about the state of a process, generally used for post-mortem debugging on Windows.

[crash-dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash-dumps) summary (440 items):

> A core dump or crash dump consists of the recorded state of the working memory of a computer program at a specific time, generally when the program has terminated abnormally

[coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump) summary (462 items):

> A core dump represents the state of working memory of a Unix program at a specific time, often when the program has terminated abruptly.

[dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dump) summary (879 items):

> Recording the contents of memory after application or operating system failure, or by operator request, in a core dump for use in subsequent problem analysis. Also, recording a file or medium as a backup.

[memory-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-dump) summary (77 items):

> A memory dump is the recorded state of the working memory of a computer program at a specific time.

[dumpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dumpfile) summary (23 items):

> *no description*

### My personal opinion

In general I see questions about dumps on topic. It's related to debugging, which is sometimes a necessity to programming.

With some debugging background on Windows, I'd say many of the above are duplicates and should be merged / burninated.

I'm fine distinguishing between dumps on Windows and dumps on Linux, since we are potentially not experts in both at the same time. I do not like e.g. a combination of [dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dump)+[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dump)+[linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), since it will be hard to follow favorite questions.

On the other hand I'm fine not to distinguish specifically between kernel dumps and user mode dumps, since at this level, a user mode dump calls API methods which are closely related to the kernel. Also, the tools to analyze kernel dumps and user mode dumps are the same (at least on Windows). Therefore e.g. [windows-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-dump)+[kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel) and [linux-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-dump)+[kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel) are nice.

I'd of course not touch the programming language specific dumps (not mentioned above) e.g. [thread-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-dump), [heap-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-dump) for Java (maybe those can be combined, but I'm not an expert here) and SQL-related dumps ([pg-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pg-dump), [mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqldump)) etc.

### Proposal

I'd leave [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump), since that's IMHO the most widely used term for Linux.

I'd leave [crash-dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash-dumps), since that's a good term for Windows, even in case of a deadlock.

I don't like the term [minidump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minidump), since it is user mode specific. A Windows kernel dump is called *full dump*, not *minidump*. Since I don't want to distinguish between user mode and kernel dumps, this one should be burninated. Since it seems to be Windows related (from the tag wiki), it should mainly be replaced by [crash-dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash-dumps).

[memory-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-dump) is probably easy to assign to [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump) or [crash-dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash-dumps).

[dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dump) and [dumpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dumpfile) are too general ("recording a file or medium as backup", OMG), so that needs to be decided case-by-case.

In any case, the tag wiki needs editing for clarification, potentially "DO NOT USE" for [dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dump) and [dumpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dumpfile).

### Discussion

Maybe I didn't get the Linux part right. Is a user mode dump also called [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump)? (core sounds much like kernel stuff)

Happy voting.

Comment: 'dumps on Windows' - Ah, the infamous Redmond Steamer.

Comment: Yes, on Linux, a kernel panic results in a core dump, same term as for processes.

Comment: I'm not sure singling out windows as *special* is that useful, but I might be wrong. Anyway, if we do the tag should unambiguously only refer to windows.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287649/dump-the-core

Comment: I think the term minidump is too pervasive and common in Microsoft's own terminology in their tooling and documentation to get rid of it.

Comment: @vcsjones: We could define it as a synonym I guess. I just see that there are many crash-dumps posts and only a few minidump posts

Answer (score 6):

"Minidump" has a specific meaning: on Windows, a minidump is a *selective* archive of a process's memory, containing sufficient information to reconstruct the state of the process at the time the dump was created (usually *but not necessarily* a crash) but excluding areas that are either unnecessary for this purpose or can easily be retrieved later (for example: the program's code itself, along with those of supporting libraries, can be stored and retrieved by the debugger separately without requiring them to be duplicated in every. single. dump).

This distinction is rather important because of how minidumps are created and the tooling involved in their use. Full dumps also exist, and *not just for kernel debugging!*

Why do you want to remove this tag?

Comment: Ok... Now that I took the time to write an answer here, I checked your profile - I strongly suspect you already know all this. Which just leaves me *more* confused; what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The number of upvotes you received on this answer makes me believe that people do not know enough about memory dumps... The name "minidump" is confusing. Minidumps are not available in kernel mode. And a full user mode dump contains less memory that a minidump with all options. Microsoft says "In user mode, a minidump is always preferable over a full dump".

Comment: From file format point of view, AFAIK, full user mode dumps and minidumps are the same. The same applies for crash dumps. So why should we have two tags for the same thing? We also have synonyms for other tags, so why shouldn't we have synonyms for minidump and crash-dump?

Comment: BTW, to me, this answer is not an answer, since it leaves too many points open, does only discuss minidumps and not all the other tags. Finally it closes with a question, which is an indicator to me that this should have been a comment for clarification.

Comment: So, this is why [I **strongly** encourage people not to lump multiple tags into a single request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) - it makes discussing them hard if not impossible (how many comments would I have to respond to right now if I'd covered every tag in your request and you'd written two responses to each?) I don't particularly care about the rest of these - lump 'em all into [tag:memory-dump] if that works and post a [meta-tag:retag-request].

Comment: Anyway, in my experience "minidump" is generally used to refer to both the APIs that create them and the files that are actually created, with *occasional* confusion on MSDN where "mini dump" is used for the product of some options and not others (realistically, we can probably ignore these). Having a tag for the API is probably useful; we could make due with [tag:minidumpwritedump] if necessary, but why?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be offensive. Well, ... I could have put two of those tags into the request only. A month later burninate the next, and so on. And nobody would have had the complete picture in mind, thus the result might be even more messy than before. If you had covered all tags, the answer would have needed more effort, for sure. Perhaps you'd have come to a different conclusion then. 'memory-dump' is a tag with low usage, so I guess it's not the term people would use. Of course we can force them by making everything else a duplicate

Comment: The whole point of synonyms is to make tags that conceptually mean the same thing *actually resolve to the same tag* - so it's not particularly important if one is somewhat more common that another, as long as we don't have 10 that are all used regularly. If you don't like [memory-dump] then propose [crash-dump] or [core] or whatever suits your fancy; as long as they're conceptually **identical** then it doesn't matter that much. However, I strongly disagree that [tag:minidump] is **identical** in either meaning or use here; related, yes, but why is that a problem?

Comment: For me it is a problem, because [minidump] is a synonym to [crash-dump]. Maybe it's not, then I should definitely learn about the difference and retract my burnination request. Let me ask that on Stack Overflow and hope that someone like Hans Passant has a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and discuss this question (which is obviously very uninteresting for people)

Answer (score -2):

This question didn't receive much attention and it's impossible to add bounties here.

I started working on the topic,

- added a tag wiki for [dumpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dumpfile) with the statement "DO NOT USE"
- edited tag wiki for [memory-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-dump) with clarification on its usage and potential better tags
- retagged questions in [dumpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dumpfile) leaving 5 questions in the tag at the moment.
- proposed a synonym for [minidump](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crash-dumps/synonyms)

And I'll slowly continue if nobody stops me :-)