# Tag warning for [core]?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-tips

The [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) tag (1433 questions) has a description of:

> A core dump file contains an image of a process's memory, usually produced during a crash

However, I've noticed many questions which misuse the tag and use it to describe the "core concepts" of a language. Or possibly from some sort of course on "core Java" etc. Examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45561352) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45576064) (I edited the tag out of those). Should there be a tag warning for [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core)? Separately, should we make it a synonym of [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump)? It seems any questions legitimately tagged with the former could also be tagged with the latter. Burnination has been [requested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287649) before, but that question is dead since 2015.

The warning would state something about how the tag is not for "core" parts of a language or technology but rather for core dumps.

Comment: Seems to be used for .NET core as well

Comment: It is a very ambiguous tag. The first thing that came to my mind was CPU core, as in the actual CPU stripped of peripheral hardware. This tag should most likely just be burninated.

Answer (score 9):

If tag warnings were actually effective, we wouldn't have users posting questions with tags that say, "DO NOT USE".

I'd encourage instead that we look to clean this one up and eliminate any ambiguity of its usage.  "core" is too broad of a topic to cover anyway, and [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coredump) seems like a suitable synonym, but we'd want to <s>nuke</s> retag any questions unrelated to that first.