# Rename the [core] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

The tag info page for the [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) tag describes:

> Use this tag to refer to processor cores or questions related to threads and parallel processing. For questions about .Net Core, please use the [.net-core] tag.

I notice that many users use the [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) tag along with [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) instead of the correct [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) tag. I even did a retagging in some questions myself.

A search for [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) tag yields 2,883 questions, [core and .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core+.net) 768 questions, and [core and asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core+asp.net) 333 questions.

Searching in Meta I found other old questions about the tag being misused for other things:

- [Dump the [core]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287649/dump-the-core)
- [Tag warning for [core]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355050/tag-warning-for-core)
- [Clarify or remove the [core] tag for new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250910/clarify-or-remove-the-core-tag-for-new-users)

For parallel-processing, we already have a tag [parallel-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parallel-processing), and to threads we have [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading).

Just the name `core` is ambiguous and many users don't read the description, so it has a potential to cause a lot of mistagging.

I propose rename to something like `processor-core` or to burninate the tag entirely.

Comment: Burninate the [tag:core] tag — it adds very little, even retagged to the hypothetical [tag:processor-core] tag, and is not helping SO.  The many questions tagged with both [tag:core] and [tag:.net] should be retagged with [tag:.net-core] (after checking, but it will be the correct action most of the time).  The not quite so many questions tagged with both [tag:core] and [tag:asp.net] should probably be given much the same treatment, but I'm less sure of that (should the [tag:asp.net] be left with [tag:.net-core], for example).  That needs more of an SME (subject-matter expert) to pontificate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [tag:core] and [tag:asp.net] should be edited into [tag:asp.net-core]. It gets tiring to edit so many questions that incorrectly use [tag:asp.net] for [tag:asp.net-core] questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: agreed.  As someone who spends a lot of time talking about CPU cores on Stack Overflow, IDK if I've ever used that tag for that meaning either.   That's what [tag:cpu-architecture] is for. I have no answers in `[core]`, and probably never added it in an edit. We don't need a tag to specify a CPU core separate from the shared caches / memory controllers and other on-chip stuff that isn't a core. (cpu-architecture is pretty low-traffic, and it's already inherent in most questions whether it's about internals of a single core or not.)

Comment: I have bad news. .NET Core is being renamed as of about next month. I wouldn't bother with this until the net tag for .NET version 5 (with its new name that I somehow don't know yet) is established.

Comment: @Joshua I don't know how the tags for the .Net family with be in SO, but I think we should have an agreed solution for this before the changes (if any) to the .Net tags take place, so they all could be corrected at the same time.

Comment: No matter if we rename the tag or burninate it, I think it should be blocked for recreation. As the old questions point out, this tag has being misused in the past, has being renamed and/or burninate, and it continue to reappear and cause new issues.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: is there an easy way to explain to a Unix programmer the differences between [tag:asp.net], [tag:asp.net-core], [tag:.net], [tag:.net-core]?  Or is it sufficiently complex that's it's best left to those with a need to know, rather than those (like me) who don't have a real need to know.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's actually simple. .NET Core is a re-write of .NET Framework without some of the libraries (like WCF, WWF) and ASP.NET Core is a re-write of ASP.NET Framework without WebForms. Both "Core" are just the "next-gen" and, most importantly, open source. For a Unix programmer, the main difference is "cannot run natively" (.NET/ASP.NET) vs "can run natively" (.NET Core/ASP.NET Core)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Thanks.